# NerdDinner Example and issues

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, freeze, nerddinner

I am using VS2010 and Sql Server 2008 in Windows 7 64 bit OS. I have downloaded NERD dinner example and tried to run the example. Everything is fine until I try to login using Open Id. I have tried to loging using Yahoo and Google Accounts. After successful sign in in the Pop up window, the control is not transferred to application or didnt throw any error. It was just hanging there itself. It hangs the entire internet explorer. I cannot select any other IE window that I have already opened. My VS2010 also got hang and finally I ended up in killing the process and reopen the project again. Please help me to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you whitelisted localhost with the DotNetOpenAuth library? You can do this in the web.config by adding this:

```
<dotNetOpenAuth>
    <messaging>
        <untrustedWebRequest>
            <whitelistHosts>
                <add name="localhost"/>
            </whitelistHosts>
        </untrustedWebRequest>
    </messaging>
</dotNetOpenAuth>
```